# How do I get my Java code to display results after connection?

Tags: java, php, html

I have java code which connects to a PHP script I've written and posts to it. The PHP contacts an API for evaluation and returns the results in html format.

The Java appears to work, but in Eclipse the result is raw html, not rendered form.

I would like to get my results to launch in a browser. I tried placing it in my xampp folder, but that did nothing, it just downloaded the Java script upon clicking the file.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this? I am open to changing the PHP code somehow to have it just return the variables and having Java create some form for the user to see. I'm just not so adept at Java right now. Ideas and examples are great!

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class Connect {


    public void POSTDATA() {
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
        // Construct data
        String data = URLEncoder.encode("ipaddress", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("98.36.2.53", "UTF-8");


        // Send data
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost/myfiles/WorkingVersion.php");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(data);
        wr.flush();

        // Get the response
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
     }
        wr.close();
        rd.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) could be your friend in this battle

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I'm facing a similar problem with an Android App. Do you know if this type of code as well as JSoup are capable of running on Android? For clarity sake, can all Java be imported into Android?

Comment: First give it a try, if the code doesn't work then come back and make a new question for the new problem(s).

Comment: I am confused by your question are you trying to dump pretty printed HTML on you console or what?

Answer (score 0):

Your Java application simply connects to the server and does a POST with ipaddress=98.36.2.53. If you want to display the result in a browser, why use Java anyway?

Several easy solutions are:

- Rewrite your PHP script to accept the parameter via GET and access it via an URL from the Webbrowser `http://localhost/myfiles/WorkingVersion.php?ipaddress=98.36.2.53`
- Write an HTML page that uses a form to POST the data - e.g. by having an `<input type="hidden" name="ipaddress" value="98.36.2.53">`. You will need user interaction to post the from, but maybe this is sufficient
- Use JavaScript to access the server, do the POST request and read the data. As JavaScript runs in the browser, it is easy to display it on the webpage (e.g. by using jQuery's [.html( htmlString )](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method.